# How to run a MS Access macro from python

Tags: python, macros, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to run an existing Microsoft Access Macro from a python script.
What I currently have is

```
import win32api,time
from win32com.client import Dispatch

strDbName = 'Exit.mdb'
objAccess = Dispatch("Access.Application")
objAccess.Visible = False
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(strDbName)
objDB = objAccess.CurrentDb()
objAccess.run('test')
objAccess.Application.Quit()
```

When I run this I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "accessmacro.py", line 10, in <module>  
    objAccess.run('test')  
  File "<COMObject Access.Application>", line 2, in run  
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, u"Microsoft    Office  Access can't find the procedure 'test.'", None, -1, -2146825771), None)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Run Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214047%28office.12%29.aspx) expects the name of a "user-defined Function or Sub procedure".  But, if 'test' is the name of a macro, use [RunMacro Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220713%28office.11%29.aspx)

```
objAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro('test')
```