# Error executing a MS Access macro from Python

Tags: python, ms-access

I'm trying to run a macro from Python. Said macro works fine when executed from Access itself, but I'm trying to do it with the following Python code (handily stolen from [How to run a MS Access macro from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177984/how-to-run-a-ms-access-macro-from-python)):

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

access_obj = Dispatch("Access.Application")
access_obj.Visible = False
access_obj.OpenCurrentDatabase("my_database_file.accdb")
access_obj.DoCmd.RunMacro("my_macro")
access_obj.DoCmd.CloseDatabase()
```

Executing the penultimate line (`...RunMacro("my_macro")`) unfortunately results in the following opaque error message:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, 'You canceled the previous operation.', 'vbaac10.chm', 5738, -2146826287), None)
```

Any idea what this even means?

Comment: If you test again with `access_obj.Visible = True`, does anything in the Access application window provide details about the error situation?

Comment: @HansUp: that... seems to have worked. And now with `Visible` set to `False` it works as well, despite me not having changed anything. I'll leave the question up though, because your suggestion is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

If you name the macro "AutoExec" it will run automatically when you open the database.

Source:  [Create a macro that runs when you open a database](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-a-macro-that-runs-when-you-open-a-database-98ba1508-dcc6-4e0f-9698-a4755e548124)

> An AutoExec macro is just a macro that is named AutoExec. When a
>   database starts, Access runs the AutoExec macro before it runs any
>   other macros or VBA code.

Comment: But, uh, suppose I don't want to run it every time I open the database. :P

Comment: Good point.  You can open the db without running the macro by holding shift when you open it.

Comment: Or...remove the close database command and put it as the last step in my_macro.