# How to run a MS Access sub/function from python with parameters?

Tags: python, vba, database, function, parameters

I know that I can run with python MS access macros (which then run a MS access VBA function) as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177984/how-to-run-a-ms-access-macro-from-python). However, access macros seem not to be able to use parameters.

Is there any possibility to run a Access VBA sub or function directly from python and passing paramters to it? I tried with application.run but that wasn't succcessful.

Thanks for any help.

**VBA Code:**

```
Public Function doNothing()
    MsgBox "Test"
End Function
```

**Access Macro3:**
Runs exactly this Function

**Python**:

```
import win32api
from win32com.client import Dispatch

objAccess = Dispatch("Access.Application")
objAccess.Visible = True
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(destinationName)

#Working with macro: (but no parameters possible)
objAccess.DoCmd.RunMacro('Macro3') 

#Not working: direct function call
#objAccess.Run('doNothing')

#Also not working:
#objDB = objAccess.CurrentDb()
#objDB.Run('doNothing')

objAccess.Application.Quit()
```

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you able to run the Access code from another VBA host such as Excel for example?

Comment: Thanks, Tim, this was the right hint to eventually find the solution I describe below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it working: First, I tried to get the call to Access VBA running from Excel.

**Excel VBA Code:**

```
Public Sub openAccess()

Dim acc As Access.Application
Set acc = New Access.Application
    With acc
        .Application.Visible = True
        .OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Temp\test.accdb"
         With .Application
            .Eval ("doNothing()")
         End With
        .Quit
    End With
Set acc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Then I could find a solution for Python as well.

**Python Code:**

```
import win32api,time
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from datetime import date, datetime
  
destinationName = "C:\Temp\test.accdb"
    
#now get the db object and open the  db
objAccess = Dispatch("Access.Application")
objAccess.Visible = True       
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(destinationName)
    
    
#calling a function does work
objAccess.Application.Eval('doNothing()')
    
objAccess.Application.Quit()
```

Now, if we need to use function parameters, note that in this call Eval() does take parameters as string only, e.g. for a date parameter:

```
strDay = date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
objAccess.Application.Eval('doNothing("' + strDay + '")')
```

Hence, afterwards the **Access VBA** code needs to translate the input date string back into a date again:

```
Public Function doNothing(inputDate As String)
    MsgBox CDate(inputDate) - 10
End Function
```